# Zend in Xampp configure routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, xampp

I have some existing Zend API's (not MVC apps) I am trying to copy locally so that I can debug them.

I have set up Xampp, copied the Zend application and updated dependencies through composer, the API has multiple classes each with their own set of functions including `cars.php`, `buildings.php`

A simple example is cars.php will contain something like:

```
class cars{
    public function search($term) {
    // do search...
    return $result;
    }
}
```

I can browse to `http://localhost/cars.php` without error, but the way we use it on the server is to browse to `http://server/cars/search?term=red` to search for red cars, which returns JSON that is consumed by other applications.

How do I set up 'routing' (there is no actual controller or anything) in Xampp and NetBeans so that I can debug something like `http://localhost/cars/search?term=red` which will take me through and hit a breakpoint in the `search` function of the `cars.php` class?

Alternatively, if I have this completely wrong (I am new to PHP) is there another way I can browse to `localhost/cars.php/search?term=red` thanks.